# Are 'Conveyor Belt' Chess variants studied?

Tags: chess-variants

A 'Conveyor Belt' Chess variant is where rows (And the pieces on them) of the chessboard move left, right, up or down based on different criteria.

I've not seen or heard of a chess variant where rows of a chess board move.

Are these a known and studied variant?

Comment: Since the only site I can find it on is that one link above, I would say that it is little known, at best, and it is doubtful that anyone really studies it.

Comment: @PhishMaster I didn't add that link, and that's not what I'm talking about. I think they came up with something similar though.

Comment: Well, I Googled only "conveyor chess variant", and the only links returned were related to that one page, and one other that referenced it. I still think you are not going to find much. Sorry.

Comment: @PhishMaster that in itself is an answer

Comment: It's hard for anyone to definitively say "no, nobody has ever studied this" because it's impossible to be proven right and rather easy to be proven wrong.

Comment: @ D M, exactly. It is hard to prove a negative.

Answer (score 2):

It's not studied to my knowledge. This is my first time hearing of such a variant.